# Bash: concatenate multiple files and add "\newline" between each?

Tags: bash, file, cat

I have a small Bash script that takes all Markdown files of a directory, and merge them into one like this:

```
for f in *.md; do (cat "${f}";) >> output.md; done
```

It works well. Now I'd like to add the string "\newline" between each document, something like this:

```
for f in *.md; do (cat "${f}";) + "\newline" >> output.md; done
```

How can I do that? The above code obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the literal string `"\newline"`, try this:

```
for f in *.md; do cat "$f"; echo "\newline"; done > output.md
```

This assumes that `output.md` doesn't already exist. If it does (and you want to include its contents in the final output) you could do:

```
for f in *.md; do cat "$f"; echo "\newline"; done > out && mv out output.md
```

This prevents the error `cat: output.md: input file is output file`.

If you want to overwrite it, you should just `rm` it before you start.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
for f in *.md; do cat "${f}"; echo; done > output.md
```

You can add an `echo` command to add a newline. To improve performance I would recommend to move the write `>` outside the `for` loop to prevent reading and writing of file at every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a funny possibility, using `ed`, the standard editor:

```
ed -s < <(
    for f in *.md; do
        [[ $f = output.md ]] && continue
        printf '%s\n' "r $f" a '\newline' .
    done
    printf '%s\n' "w output.md" "q"
)
```

(I've inserted a line to exclude `output.md` from the inserted files).

For each file:

- `r $f`: `r` is `ed`'s *insert file* command,
- `a`: `ed` starts a newline after the current line for editing,
- `\newline`: well, we're insertion mode, so `ed` just inserts this,
- `.`: to stop insert mode.

At the end, we `w`rite the buffer to the file `output.md` and `q`uit.